# how to check virtual keyboard is up in android using appium?

Tags: android, node.js, appium

I'm using nodejs..

In ios I checked whether element //uiakeyboard is displayed or not..
I don't know how to check in android..

Is there any way to check whether android virtual keyboard is up or not??

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any way to do this. If you are ok with the keyboard not popping up at all, Try using "unicodeKeybord" capability. Appium will install a keyboard which does not have any UI.